# Ember non-cli application, how remove #(hash ) from url?

Tags: ember.js

How to remove #(hash) from URL in ember application (non - CLI).
I am using ember v2.15.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [location documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/configuring-ember/specifying-url-type/#toc-toggle).

You can specify which type you want.

Setting `location` to `history` on `EmberRouter` will remove the hash from the url and instead use browser history. To disable it altogether, set `location` to `none`.

```
const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: 'none',
  rootURL: '/'
})
```

Comment: Your code has a router in it, yes? Add the `location` attribute with the value `none` to it.

Comment: The `Router`, not the `Route`.

Comment: This worked for me : 
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
 location: 'history',
 rootURL: '/root/'
});  :: Thanks